# Does lower density of the natural numbers satisfy triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory

The lower density of a set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is defined to be

$$d_l(A) = \liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{|A\cap \{1,...,n\}|}{n}$$

while upper density is given by 
$$d_u(A) = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{|A\cap \{1,...,n\}|}{n}$$

It is easy to prove that for $A,B\subset \mathbb{N}$,
$$d_u(A\cup B)\leq d_u(A)+d_u(B)$$

However, I am having trouble proving or disproving the same for $d_l$. Can anyone please help me out with this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive integer $n$, and for $n!\le j<(n+1)!$ ,let $j\in A$ iff $n$ is odd, and let $j\in B$ iff $n$ is even. Then $d_l(A)=d_l(B)=0$ and $A\cup B=N$ so $ d_l(A\cup B)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made some computations and found a decreasing subsequence trend in both cases for An. If you have a source for a proper proof, please let me know, as I have been unable to do it. Cheers :)

Comment: For even $n >0$ we have $|A\cap \{1,.., (n+1)!\}|/(n+1)! \le n!/(n+1)!=1/(n+1)$ .For odd $n$ we have $ |B\cap \{1,..,(n+1)!\}|/(n+1)!\le n!/(n+1)!=1/(n+1).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a set $A$ of lower density $0$ and upper density $1$. Let $B$ be the complement of $A$. Then $A\cup B$ has lower density $1$, while each of the sets $A$ and $B$  has lower density $0$.

Comment: This is an interesting proposition! Thanks! I have an idea of how to construct this. I mean one can just keep selecting integers in a pattern so that you have an increasing subsequence and a decreasing subsequence for An/n However, I am confused on how to make a sequence where I can explicitly state all the elements of A.